# mail client outlook focused inbox

Tags: mail, email-client

I am looking for a mail client that allows me to only see the focused mails from Outlook. I have tested all different type of mail clients available in Ubuntu. But all of them don't give the options to show only the focused inbox. So then I get all the mails in the inbox. Which shows a lot of junk mail that I don't need.

Comment: Have you found any yet?